# драйвер для работы с LBA в своей ОС

Tags: c, ассемблер, ос, osdev

Необходимо сделать драйвер для работы с LBA...

все необходимое сделал, но не могу понять, разве можно ( я могу ) использовать массив ( из Си ), как сегмент в ассемблере? Вся штука в том, что нужно передать указатель по модели сегмент:регистр.

вот примерный код, из моей функции `sys_writeLBA`:

```
int sys_writeLBA(LBA info){
    byte func = LBA_FS_WRITE;
    int32 jsbits = info.dap.sector << (8*4);
    int32 ssbits = info.dap.sector;

    asm volatile("pushal"); // push to stack all x32 regs

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // подготавливаем данные для вызова прерывания LBA

    asm volatile(
        "push %%es\n"
        "push %%bx"
    ); // сохраняем es и bx



    // используем buf, как сегмент, а оффсет - 0

    asm(
        "movl (%0),%%es" // помещаем в es наш указатель на начало буфера
            :
            : "m" (info.dap.buf)
            :
    );
    asm(
        "movl $0,%%bx" // здесь 0 так как смещение в буфере 0
    );

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // теперь нужно положить все данные в стек


    asm(
        "push %0\n"
            :
            : "r" (ssbits)
            :
    ); // кладём старшие биты номера сектора

    asm(
        "push %0\n"
            :
            : "r" (jsbits)
            :
    ); // младшие биты номера сектора

    asm("push %%es"); // сегмент
    asm("push %%bx"); // смещение в буфере
    asm("push $%0": : "M" (info.dap.sector_count) : );

    asm("push $0x10"); // размер структуры DAP

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    asm("movl $%0,%%ah" : : "M" (func) : ); // номер функции ( чтение )
    asm("movl $%0,%%dl" : : "M" (info.hdrive) : ); // номер диска ( с нуля )
    asm("movl %%esp,%%esi"); // устанавливаем указатель на структуру DAP

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    asm("int $0x13"); // вызываем LBA

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // recovery used registers and clear stack

    // ...

    asm volatile("popal"); // pop from stack all x32 regs

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

про примерную работу LBA прочитал на хабре...

Comment: немного кода вопросу не повредило бы...

Comment: гм... всё равно не особо понятно, о чём вопрос... для начала, всё в реальном или защищённом режиме происходит? какая длина адресов? в какой модели памяти работает/собирается Си'шный код?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под моделью памяти ?

Comment: я подразумевал, что сишный код компилируется в бинарник, который предназначен для работы в плоском адресном пространстве, т.е., как обычно, у указателей 16/32/64-х битный адрес без сегмента или, может быть, у компилятора есть какая-то встроенная поддержка дальних указателей по сегментной модели (маловероятно на сегодняшний день и ЕМНИП в gcc её нет, но уточнить стоит)...

Comment: я вот как раз и пытался понять как найти адрес ( в формате сегмент сдвиг ) на массив, для записи туда сегментов !?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я подумал, как можно использовать массив как страницу ( сегмент ), для использования, при указании буфера в LBA прерывании

Comment: @Fat-Zer что думаете ?

Comment: опять же, основные вопросы, в каком формате у тебя адрес после компилятора? и в каком режиме это всё происходит? что за «LBA прерываниие»? я не особо понимаю, что в принципе ты пытаешься сделать... пойми, что посторонние люди в отличие от тебя не тратили часы времени над твоим наколенным проектом, так что никто здесь с полуслова не поймёт, о чём ты говоришь... так что рассказывай __в подробностях__, с примерами кода и, на всякий пожарный, как ты всё это собираешь/запускаешь... без этого я пока не могу сказать ничего определённого...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я дам объяснение, но не сразу

Comment: в этой теме ( _osdev_ ) я на уровне **junior**, так что могу не всё знать...

Comment: добавил более расширенное описание проблемы

Comment: сразу надо было начать с того, что «пытаюсь вызвать функцию `AH=0x43` `int 0x13`». Теперь о грустном, `int 0x13` работает только в [*реальном режиме*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC), который может исполнять только 16-битный код, но обычный gcc не умеет генерировать таковой, так что, если ты не разжился каким-нибудь весьма странным компилятором, то этот метод всё равно не будет работать. А у «странных компиляторов» есть свои встроенные методы для работы с длинными указателями.

Comment: По коду: много ошибок и весьма странных конструкций, в частности вот это: `info.dap.sector << (8*4)`, вообще говоря UB, а на gcc выдаст `0`... чисто математически перевести 24-битный адрес в сегментный можно так: `seg = addr >>4; off = addr & 0xff;`

Comment: И ещё хинт: в одну ассемблерную вставку можно включать сразу много команд...

Comment: тогда вопрос, если LBA работает только в реальном режиме, тогда мне придётся рыться в доках SATA и AHCI ??

Comment: и писать драйвер для SATA и AHCI ??

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, самое простое, что можно сделать — [ATA PIO](https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode) драйвер. Но авторитетно здесь я утверждать что-то уже не могу...

Comment: а где доки по **ATA PIO** можно найти ?

Comment: на вскидку не подскажу... в какой-нить спецификации ATA должны быть... основное, что тебе нужно — это команды регистры, которые map'ятся к портам x86... но в принципе на osdev основное, что нужно дано...